# Desktop Folder Redirection Consistency

Tags: group-policy, user-profile, folder-redirection

I have changed our Desktop folder redirection policy to point to a new share on the server. Some computers are accepting the new policy and displaying the new shortcuts. Others display no icons and others display the old share.

How can I force a policy update on all workstations so they all show the new shortcuts? Running `gpupdate` does not have an effect, and neither does deleting the profile from System Properties - Advanced.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the resultant set of policy mmc snapin on the misbehaving systems. It is possible an other policy is overriding your new settings. Verify that the group policy is actually bound to the OUs that the troubled workstations reside in.

Comment: RSoP found a conflict. Never even knew RSoP existed because it wasnt in group policy manager. Also the policy was set not to apply to XP and 2000 systems - little checkbox?!

Comment: Yeah.. RSoP is a great (and apparently very under utilized) tool.

Comment: It may also take up two logout/login's on each account to full change the settings, and you should see messaging telling you that in System Event Log